# Can someone explain javascript console log of this array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging, console.log

I'm trying to push some objects into an array.

This is done in a cursor loop in an 'onsuccess' function of a cursor search using indexedDB.

It uses continue() to iterate through the matching objects.

I'm pushing these onto an array with arrayname.push.

I am examining the finished array with a console.log(arrayname) outside this function and the array appears to contain 4 objects and yet has a length of zero. It also mentions a length of 4 and shows the object.

I have attached a picture which illustrates console.log(arrayname).

[illustration on console.log(arrayname)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVqCM.png)

I'm not clear on what the log is telling me - where are those objects? The result I have is by clicking on the Array [ ] that appears in the console which is the logged result.

Thanks for any help in untangling this.

Moray

Comment: Please post your code here :)

Comment: The length of zero that you are seeing in `__proto__` is `Array.prototype.length` which is always `0`. But still, yes the array has a zero length when it is logged but will have contents when you inspect it.

Comment: Great thanks all - sorry I didn't post code, was basically trying to make sense of the message.